# На мобильных разрешениях при вызове выпадающего меню появляется скролл - как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, menu

Есть двухуровневое меню с выпадающим подменю на `bootstrap`. На мобильных разрешениях, когда меню сворачивается в бутерброд, нижние выпадающие списки не помещаются в область меню и появляется справа в нем скролл. Как этот момент можно исправить?
[фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/ydcMQ/1222/)

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding:15px 15px;">Название проекта</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Меню
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Меню
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Меню
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: у Вас .navbar-collapse {
     max-height: 340px; ...} либо убрать, либо больше сделать значение максимальной высоты

Comment: @Elena Semenchenko а как убрать? http://jsfiddle.net/ydcMQ/1223/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстрое решение - выставьте `overflow-y: visible` у `.navbar-collapse.in`:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```